# Перевод на новую строку после вывода значений внутреннего массива

Tags: java, массивы

Почему `System.out.println()` выполняет последующий переход на новую строку после вывода пяти значений, а не после вывода каждого значения?

```
public class TwoDArrays {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int twoD[][] = new int[4][5];
        int i, j, k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                twoD[i][j] = k;
                k++;
            }
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В этом коде нет ошибок. Пример кода из книги Java 8 Полное руководство 9 издание.

Comment: 3 3 3 3 3 новая строка 2 3 4 1 3 новая строка 3 3 4 2 3 новая строка 2 3 4 5 3, если не понимаете почему так , то читайте заново учебник шилдта! (цифры на бум написал)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы не выставили фигурные скобки после оператора цикла, то в цикле будет исполняться только следующий за ним метод, т.е.

```
for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
```

Чтобы оба метода вывода на консоль исполнялись во внутреннем цикле напишите так:

```
for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```